# How to change defined in WSDL schema Root Element of soap request body, using node-soap

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, node-soap

I'm trying to make a SOAP request to external API using node-soap. The Root element inside Body is taken from WSDL schema. Is it possible to change it somehow before request?

Here's the client creation and request sending:

```
let client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdl, soapClientOptions);
let result = await client.MakeCalculationAsync({});
console.log(result);
```

XML produced by node-soap is:

```
<soap:Body>
    <IIntegrationService_MakeCalculation_InputMessage> 
    </IIntegrationService_MakeCalculation_InputMessage>
</soap:Body>
```

But the root element should be `<MakeCalculation>`, not `<IIntegrationService_MakeCalculation_InputMessage>`, cause in last case the response results in an error.

I found some workaround which is quite dodgy in my opinion.
You can use **postProcess** method to replace text in xml like this:

```
client.MakeCalculation({}, (err, result, rawResponse, soapHeader, rawRequest) => {
            console.log(result);
          }, {
            postProcess: (_xml) => {
              return _xml
.replace('IIntegrationService_MakeCalculation_InputMessage', 'MakeCalculation')
.replace('/IIntegrationService_MakeCalculation_InputMessage', '/MakeCalculation');
            }
          }
        );
```

But as I said it's not a good way and you can't use it in Async way as well.

P.S. There was very similar question here [How can I configure the Root Element of a node-soap request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636977/how-can-i-configure-the-root-element-of-a-node-soap-request-body) But still no awnsers.